# Get familiy tree of child category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which i store a tree structure. Basically the family structure is

```
Category > Sub category > sub sub category
```

The parent here is the one with parent_id of 0.
I need to get the family structure of any category through sql. The table looks like

```
cat_id | parent_id | name
-------------------------
1      |    0      | a
2      |    0      | b
3      |    1      | c
4      |    2      | d
5      |    3      | e
6      |    4      | f
```

so for the cat_id of 4, the the result i need is

```
c1.cat_id | c.name | c2.cat_id  |  c2.name   | c3.cat_id |   c3.name
2              b        4            d           null          null
```

so for the cat_id of 6, the the result i need is

```
c1.cat_id | c.name | c2.cat_id  |  c2.name   | c3.cat_id |   c3.name
2              b        4            d           6             f
```

This is the code am currently using,which gives more than one row for each result

```
SELECT c1.name cat1, c1.cat_id cat1_id,c2.name cat2, c2.cat_id cat2_id ,c3.name cat3, c3.cat_id cat3_id
 FROM ea_category AS c1
  JOIN ea_category AS c2 ON (c2.parent_id = c1.cat_id)
  JOIN ea_category AS c3 ON (c3.parent_id = 0)
where c1.cat_id = 4
```

What am i doing wrong

Comment: it gives more than two rows for each result because there are two cats with `parent_id = 0`, so your last `join` joins to both of them

Comment: yes, i know, but i only want the parent of the grand child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to retrieve parent id

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getparentCatId

   ( id INT ) RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
 DECLARE parent_catid INT; 
 SET parent_catid = (SELECT parent_id FROM categoryTable WHERE cat_id=id);
 RETURN parent_catid;
END
```

Create another function for parent category name

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getCatName

   ( id INT ) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN 
 DECLARE categoryName Varchar(10); 
 SET categoryName  = (SELECT name FROM categoryTable WHERE cat_id=id);
 RETURN categoryName;
END
```

Then use it like below

```
SELECT cat_id, name 
       ,fn_getparentCatId(cat_id) , fn_getCatName(fn_getparentCatId(cat_id))
       ,fn_getparentCatId(fn_getparentCatId(cat_id)) , fn_getCatName(fn_getparentCatId(fn_getparentCatId(cat_id)))

FROM categoryTable
WHERE cat_id=6
```